# Some sections in the CSS can't be recognised

Tags: css

Why is it that sometimes some sections in the CSS aren't recognised and sometimes they are? My codes are as follows:

```
<section class="generalContainer"><time>8 September 2016</time></section>
<section class="oath-takingContainer"><time>12 October 2016</time></section>

section.generalContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -15px 0 10px -15px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    background: #868A08;
    }

section.oath-takingContainer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin: -15px 0 10px -15px;
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
background: #08088A;
}
```

The website just recognises section.generalContainer but not oath-takingContainer. I used the Chrome Inspect function and please see the right box for the CSS. The difference between generalContainer and oath-takingContainer. The former is recognised but the latter not recognised.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you cannot inspect the section.oath-takingContainer as it is placed directly *underneath* the other div by the CSS... you literally cannot right click and "inspect" it.

Here I have applied brighter colours for clarity, and moved the lower div from under the upper one, it now inspects fine.

```css
section.generalContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -15px 0 10px -15px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background: red;
}

section.oath-takingContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -15px 0 10px -15px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  background: pink;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="generalContainer"><time>8 September 2016</time></section>
<section class="oath-takingContainer"><time>12 October 2016</time></section>
```

Comment: As the OP showed a screenshot where he selects the `.oath-takingContainer` I don't think that this is an issue here.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but after several hours, it worked well. I guess, it takes time for the server to process the new code.